# Values for 'fun= ' in *apply functions

Tags: r, tapply

The *apply (apply, tapply, lapply etc.) are a very useful and straightforward method of applying a function across an array of data, with the generic structure:

```
*apply(data, function ...)
```

However, I cannot find a list of valid functions.

Can anyone provide a link to such a list?

Comment: Any function can be used.

Comment: The "Value:" section of `?apply` may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `lapply` and its variants `sapply`, `vapply` and `eapply`, the only restriction is that the function can only be vectorised over a single argument.  (All other arguments must be scalar.)  `mapply` exists to get around this restriction.

> Can anyone provide a link to such a list?

So, um, no, no-one can provide a link to such a list, because that list doesn't exist.